# Create a calculated column from row level values in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a sample table that looks like this:

| month_start_date | account_detail | budget | days_in_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | job sales | 310 | 31 |
| 2/1/2021 | job sales | 560 | 28 |
| 3/1/2021 | job sales | 930 | 31 |
| 1/1/2021 | rental sales | 2170 | 31 |
| 2/1/2021 | rental sales | 2240 | 28 |
| 3/1/2021 | rental sales | 2790 | 31 |
| 1/1/2021 | product sales | 620 | 31 |
| 2/1/2021 | product sales | 840 | 28 |
| 3/1/2021 | product sales | 1240 | 31 |

What I'm trying to do is to convert the account detail from rows to columns in SQL in addition to getting the daily budget amount by account detail type (i.e. - budget / days_in_month). I'm trying to get this desired output:

| month_start_date | daily_job_sales_budget | daily_rental_sales_budget | daily_product_sales_budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | 10 | 70 | 20 |
| 2/1/2021 | 20 | 80 | 30 |
| 3/1/2021 | 30 | 90 | 40 |

I'm still a pretty fresh SQL user, so I hope it's not too difficult. For what it's worth, here is what I've tried as a start. It sort of works ok, but I don't need the account_detail, so it's effectively tripling the number of rows I really need. I'm only looking for 1 row of data per month.

```sql
SELECT 
    account_detail
    ,month_start_date
    ,days_in_month
    ,SUM(CAST(budget as FLOAT)) as budget
    ,SUM(CAST(budget as FLOAT)) / AVG(CAST(days_in_month as FLOAT)) as budget_per_day
    ,CASE
        WHEN account_detail = 'Job Sales' 
            THEN SUM(CAST(budget as FLOAT)) / AVG(CAST(days_in_month as FLOAT))
        ELSE 0
    END AS job_sales_daily_budget
FROM public.financial_values
GROUP BY
    account_detail
    ,month_start_date
    ,days_in_month
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: It is triplicating it because you are grouping by both account_detail and month_start_date since the same account can have multiple months and starts it gives you one per each.

Comment: I'm using a custom SQL query in Tableau, connecting to a Postgres database. I get that it's tripling up because I'm grouping by account_detail, but if I remove it from my GROUP BY, I get an error message stating "ERROR: column "financial_values.account_detail" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function." Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT month_start_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN account_detail = 'Job Sales' THEN budget / days_in_month END) as daily_job_sales_budget,
       SUM(CASE WHEN account_detail = 'Rental Sales' THEN budget / days_in_month END) as daily_rental_sales_budget,
       SUM(CASE WHEN account_detail = 'Product Sales' THEN budget / days_in_month END) as daily_product_sales_budget
FROM public.financial_values
GROUP BY month_start_date;
```

I'm not sure why your query is converting budget values to a float.  If the purpose is avoid integer division, then you can instead use:

```
SELECT month_start_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN account_detail = 'Job Sales' THEN budget * 1.0 / days_in_month END) as daily_job_sales_budget,
       SUM(CASE WHEN account_detail = 'Rental Sales' THEN budget * 1.0 / days_in_month END) as daily_rental_sales_budget,
       SUM(CASE WHEN account_detail = 'Product Sales' THEN budget * 1.0 / days_in_month END) as daily_product_sales_budget
FROM public.financial_values
GROUP BY month_start_date;
```

Comment: I like this one simple and compact.  I set up an example here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ZbQMQhWMLqfRXfMD6YumF/4  using Gordon's work

Answer (score 0):

**Here goes your query:**

> ```
> create table financial_values (month_start_date date, account_detail varchar(100),    budget int, days_in_month int);
> insert into financial_values values('2021/1/1','job sales',310,   31);
> insert into financial_values values('2021/2/1','job sales',560    ,28);
> insert into financial_values values('2021/3/1','job sales',930    ,31);
> insert into financial_values values('2021/1/1','rental sales',    2170    ,31);
> insert into financial_values values('2021/2/1','rental sales',    2240    ,28);
> insert into financial_values values('2021/3/1','rental sales',    2790    ,31);
> insert into financial_values values('2021/1/1','product sales',   620 ,31);
> insert into financial_values values('2021/2/1','product sales',   840 ,28);
> insert into financial_values values('2021/3/1','product sales',   1240,   31);
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> select month_start_date,sum(case when account_detail='job sales' then daily_budget end) daily_job_sales_budget,
> sum(case when account_detail='rental sales' then daily_budget end) daily_rental_sales_budget,
> sum(case when account_detail='product sales' then daily_budget end) daily_product_sales_budget
> from
> (
>   select month_start_date, account_detail, sum(cast(budget as float))/avg(days_in_month)daily_budget
>   from financial_values
>   group by month_start_date,account_detail
> )t
> group by month_start_date
> order by month_start_date
> GO
> ```

**Output:**

> | month_start_date | daily_job_sales_budget | daily_rental_sales_budget | daily_product_sales_budget |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-01-01 | 10 | 70 | 20 |
> | 2021-02-01 | 20 | 80 | 30 |
> | 2021-03-01 | 30 | 90 | 40 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c809df1721041e03a684277aff229701)*

Comment: @FormidableData Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (MonthStart DATE NULL, Account NVARCHAR(50), Budget INT, DaysInMonth INT)

INSERT @Test (MonthStart,Account,Budget,DaysInMonth)
VALUES 
    ('1/1/2021','job sales',310,31)
    ,('2/1/2021','job sales',560,28)
    ,('3/1/2021','job sales',930,31)
    ,('1/1/2021','rental sales',2170,31)
    ,('2/1/2021','rental sales',2240,28)
    ,('3/1/2021','rental sales',2790,31)
    ,('1/1/2021','product sales',620,31)
    ,('2/1/2021','product sales',840,28)
    ,('3/1/2021','product sales',1240,31)

SELECT 
    DATENAME(MONTH,t.MonthStart) AS Month
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY,t.MonthStart,EOMONTH(t.MonthStart)) + 1 AS DaysInMonth
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN t.Account = 'Job Sales' THEN t.Budget ELSE 0 END) AS [Job Sales]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN t.Account = 'Rental Sales' THEN t.Budget ELSE 0 END) AS [Rental Sales]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN t.Account = 'Product Sales' THEN t.Budget ELSE 0 END) AS [Product Sales]
FROM @Test t
GROUP BY t.MonthStart
```

[image]